# Inner Join 2 tables, and fetch results during while

Tags: php, mysql, join

I made this query so it combines 2 tables into one so It can get the name of the office and insurance company instead of the number variable it is but its not working.

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT pat_id,pat_lname,pat_fname,pat_date,pat_loc,pat_ins,pat_show FROM patients INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins ");
```

How the offices database looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXWYG.png

How it looks when exporting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ienh4.png

I am trying to get it to show the name Hackensack instead of a 2 for the location in pat_loc when it exports. How can I get that to work?

Here is the whole statement:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT pat_id,pat_lname,pat_fname,pat_date,pat_loc,pat_ins,pat_show FROM patients INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins ");


while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
    $csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ", ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  pat_id,
  pat_lname,
  pat_fname,
  pat_date,
  office_name,
  pat_ins,
  pat_show
FROM patients
INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc
INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins
```

Update: Based on your comments below, I've come up with the following:

```
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT
        pat_id AS `user_id`,
        pat_fname as `First Name`,
        pat_lname as `Last Name`,
        pat_date as `IME Date`,
        pat_loc as `Location`,
        pat_ins as `Insurance Company`,
        pat_show as `Show(Y/N)`
    FROM patients
    INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc
    INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins
');

$csv_output = '';
$headersPrinted = false;
while ($patient = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (!$headersPrinted)
    {
        $csv_output .= implode(',', array_keys($patient))."\n";
        $headersPrinted = true;
    }

    $csv_output .= implode(',', array_values($patient))."\n";
}
```

However, with this, you're joining in the `offices` and `insurance` tables for no apparent use. I'm assuming you want to display some values from those table in place of raw IDs. In that case, you would for example replace `pat_loc` with `office_name` in the query.

Comment: You just reposted the same code I already have. But it doesnt work. I need to set:    $csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ", ";

manually with the column names

Comment: Well, I replaced the pat_loc field with office_name from the offices table which appears to be what you want. Are you saying you want the field to still be named pat_loc, but that it should contain the name rather than the actual contents of the pat_loc field?

Comment: If not, please update your question with an example of what you want the export to look like.

Comment: It currently looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/780lIT2.png

I would like it to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/bEvPWmK.png

This is my current code (I commented out the SELECT that doesnt work and throw off an error: http://pastebin.com/rkpa9Mpc

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt seem to work. I managed to fix my code a bit to show a little more info your code did more harm than good, but much appreciated for the code. I managed to also give a name for the IME COMPANY instead of it showing a number.  

What I am trying to do now, is make it show a proper name for the SHOW COLUMNS query. I have `$sql = 'SELECT pat_id as `user_id`, pat_fname as `First Name`, pat_lname as `Last Name`, pat_date as `IME Date`, pat_loc as `Location`, pat_ins as `Insurance Company`, pat_show as `Show(Y/N)`, FROM '.$table.'';`` as code but it throws off errors.

Comment: `$sql = 'SELECT pat_id as "user_id", pat_fname as "First Name", pat_lname as "Last Name", pat_date as "IME Date", pat_loc as "Location", pat_ins as "Insurance Company", pat_show as "Show(Y/N)", FROM '.$table.'';` as code but it throws off errors.`

Comment: Why are you running one query to get the column names and then another to get the rows? You're using mysql_fetch_assoc which means you get the column names as well, so there's no need for the ´SHOW COLUMNS´ query. Try the following script. What does it produce? http://pastebin.com/Ah3MG3RZ

Comment: Here is what it produces: http://i.imgur.com/nBZoiVT.png, compared to how its supposed to look: http://i.imgur.com/yIqBneX.png, basically I want to show the name of the company and location instead of the number.

Comment: There we go, I changed **pat_ins** to **ins_name** and **pat_loc** to **office_name**

Comment: One more thing, how would I combine 2 columns into one specifically the first and last name? so its cherdak, brian in one box. like: http://i.imgur.com/gfURMCf.png

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned in my answer above, changing ´pat_loc´ to ´office_name´ would give you the name of the office rather than the ID. You can combine two columns into one like this: ´SELECT pat_id AS `user_id`, CONCAT(pat_lname, ', ', pat_fname) as `Name`, ...´. If this is the answer to the question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the support the past few days. :)